# Codeigniter form_error with Bootstrap 3

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello guys I am doing a form in codeigniter to display error message. My **CSS framework** is **Bootstrap 3**.

My codes so far:
**View.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <?php
                $label_attributes = array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label');
                echo form_label('Load Balance', 'load_balance', $label_attributes); 
            ?>



            <div class="col-xs-3">
            <?php 
                $load_balance_attrs = array('class' => 'form-control', 
                                        'id' => 'load_balance', 
                                        'placeholder' => 'Load Balance', 
                                        'name' => 'load_balance', 
                                        'type' => 'number',
                                        'min' => '0',
                                        'step' => '1',  );
                echo form_input($load_balance_attrs);
            ?> 

            <?php echo form_error('load_balance', 
                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
                <p class="help-block">', '</p>'); ?>

            </div>

        </div>
```

I am trying to get this [example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation) but I have no idea how to append **.has-error** to my **.form-group** to display the error message. Do you have any ideas how to do that? Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
<div class="form-group <?php if(validation_errors()) echo 'has-error'; ?>">
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="form-group">
```